# Regex for number range from 0 to 31 excluding preceding zeros

Tags: java, regex

I have written regex from numbers from 0 to 31. It shall not allow preceding zeros.

```
[0-2]\\d|/3[0-2]
```

But it also allows preceding zeros.

```
01 invalid
02 invalid
```

Can some tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Just one question: why?

Comment: What is your use-case? Might it be more reasonable to do an `Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString)` and then test to see `if( myInt >= 0 && myInt <= 31)`?

Comment: @LanguidSquid `Integer.parseInt("01")` will return the same as `Integer.parseInt("1")`, maybe if you add a second test like `String.valueOf(myInt).equals(inputString)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV2cP6/1)

Your regex - `[0-2]\\d|/3[0-2]` - contains 2 alternatives: 1) `[0-2]\\d` matches a digit from 0-2 range first and then any 1 digit (with `\\d`), and 2) `/3[0-2]` matches `/`, then `3` and then 1 digit from 0-2 range. What is important is that without anchors (`^` and `$`) this expression will match substrings in longer strings, and will match `01` in `010`.

Since there has been some discussion about shorthand classes, here is a version with the shorthand class and here is also an example with `matches()` that requires full input to match and thus we do not need explicit anchors:

```
String pttrn = "(?:\\d|[12]\\d|3[01])";
System.out.println("31".matches(pttrn));
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/62q6mH)

Note that the backslash should be doubled here.

Comment: I would replace `[0-9]` with `\\d`.

Comment: In Java, with its escaping, I would stick with character class for readability.

Comment: @stribizhev in some cases `[0-9]` won't work in java.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose since Java doesn't have verbatim strings, this might very well be better off without escaping backslashes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj in what case(s) exactly?

Comment: Why not "^(?[12]?[0-9]|3[01])$"?

Comment: @LanguidSquid Once I asked a user to put `[0-9]` as pattern. He says that it won't for him instead `\\d` does.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Could you be a bit more specific? I can't reproduce that issue.

Comment: That doesn't mean "some cases where it won't work" @AvinashRaj, it just means that there was something in a specific user's program that caused it not to work. Perhaps his code cleans away brackets from the pattern before applying it. Or perhaps he just typed it incorrectly.

Comment: @Jashaszun: `\d` matches non-latin digits too (Hebrew, Arabic, etc). This isn't covered by the question.

Comment: @BalusC Ah, that's a much better reason.

Answer (score 2):

It is harder to maintain code with `regex` in it: see [When you should not use Regular Expressions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions)

In order to make your code more maintainable and easier for other developers to jump into and support, maybe you could consider converting your `String` to an `Integer` and then testing the value?

```
if((!inputString.startsWith("0") && inputString.length() == 2) || inputString.length() == 1){
  Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
  if( 0 <= myInt && myInt <= 31){
    //execute logic...
  }
}
```

you could also easily break this out into a utility method that is very descriptive such as:

```
private boolean isBetween0And31Inclusive(String inputString){
    try{
        if((!inputString.startsWith("0") && inputString.length() == 2) || inputString.length() == 1){
            Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
            if(0 <= myInt && myInt <= 31){
              return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }catch(NumberFormatException exception){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You got my upvote. Probably the simplest, and you could add some checks before parsing it (for example, the length of the String should be between 1 and 2, etc.)

Comment: I've always liked "if (0 <= myInt && myInt <= 31)".  It's self documenting to see that myInt is from 0 - 31 inclusive.

Comment: Now your last edit will throw an exception if inputString is a single non-digit character.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following pattern:

```
^(?:[12]?[0-9]|3[01])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another non-`Regex` approach with data validation before attempting to convert a `String` to `int`.  Here we are validating that the data is at least 1 character that is a digit, or the data is 2 characters that are digits and the first character is not a 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList() {{
       add("01");   // Bad
       add("1A");   // Bad
       add("123");  // Bad
       add("31");   // Good
       add("-1");   // Bad
       add("32");   // Bad
       add("0");    // Good
       add("15");   // Good
    }};

    for (String d : data) {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (d.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
        } else {
            char firstChar = d.charAt(0);
            if ((d.length() == 1 && Character.isDigit(firstChar)) ||
                (d.length() == 2 && 
                    (Character.isDigit(firstChar) && firstChar != '0' && 
                     Character.isDigit(d.charAt(1))))) {
                int myInt = Integer.parseInt(d);
                valid = (0 <= myInt && myInt <= 31);
            } else {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(valid ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Valid
Invalid
Invalid
Valid
Valid
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
\\b(?:[12]?\\d|3[12])\\b
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/uxivr1T5xV)

Answer (score 2):

This **regex** does not use none-capturing group:

```
^(\d|[12]\d|3[01])$
```

Explanation:

> ^ - start of line 
>  \d - single digit 0-9
>  or
>  [12]\d - tens
>   and twenties
>  or
>  3[01]  - thirty and thirty one
>  $ - line end

Java [DEMO](http://ideone.com/rJTMWZ)